# Imagem em botão da barra de navegação IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Preciso adicionar dois botões na barra de navegação do meu app, porém o que preciso de usar uma imagem externa (já importada ao projeto) ela não aparece.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         //Esse botão aparece (icone da própria biblioteca)

        let rightShareBarButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.action, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.shareTapped))

        //Esse ícone não aparece, estou tentando carregar uma imagem interna - já importada ao projeto

        let rightInfoBarButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "info.png"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.infoTapped))

        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([rightInfoBarButtonItem, rightShareBarButtonItem], animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Um palpite é que não haver espaço suficiente para os dois botões neste lado da barra. Já experimentou adicionar apenas o botão personalizado ou adicioná-lo primeiro para ver se ele aparece? Não notei nada errado no código...

Comment: Então, já coloquei dois botões que tem na própria biblioteca do xcode e apareceram os dois, inclusive já coloquei texto na qual seu tamanho é maior que o ícone e tb apareceu, a única coisa que não aparece são imagens externas...

Comment: A imagem está lá no xcassets exatamente com o nome que você tá chamando ela, certo?

Comment: Sou novo no desenvolvimento para iOS e não sabia que os ícones deveriam estar na xcassets, para mim que eram iguais as demais imagens onde basta adicionarmos ao projeto. Mas criei um novo Assets.xcassets e deu certo. Mais uma vez muito obrigado, resolveu completamente esse meu problema.

Answer (score 2):

O seu *ViewController* tem um **NavigationController** ?
Porque se ele não tiver, seus botões não irão aparecer na tela.

Como adicionar um navigationController para o seu viewController via **código**.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let controller = ViewController()

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)

    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    return true
}
```

Agora via **storyboard**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então deverá ficar assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora dentro do seu **ViewController** independente se for via *código*, ou pelo *storyboard*, isto deverá funcionar.

```
    let image = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image"))

    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: image.image, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    navigationItem.setRightBarButton(rightButton, animated: true)
```